# Grafana AWS CloudWatch Plugin Collection Rate

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there a way to change the frequency at which metrics are collected from AWS CloudWatch?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.
It's all in the grafana interface

[image: Refresh rate]

You can also customize this dropdown in the settings

[image]

Comment: That’s for refreshing the display of data it doesn’t pull the data any faster. Even set to less than a minute, most data is two to three mins behind

Comment: Also note that CloudWatch aggregates data in a minute minimum. I think it cannot be less then a minute.